# How can I formally prove this metric inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

$$d_2, d_1-\text{metrics in } R^k$$

$$d_2(x,y)=(\sum_{i=1}^{k}|x^i-y^i|^2)^{1 \over 2} \\
  d_1(x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^{k}|x^i-y^i| \\ d_2(x,y) \leq d_1(x,y) $$

I first squared both $d_2(x,y)$ and $d_1(x,y)$ to get

$(d_2(x,y))^2=(\sum_{i=1}^{k}|x^i-y^i|^2)$

$(d_1(x,y))^2=(\sum_{i=1}^{k}|x^i-y^i|)^2$

Intuitively, I understand that squaring the (non-negative) sum is greater than squaring the term inside, but how do I formally show this?

Comment: $d_1^2$ contains the squares and the double products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}(d_1(x,y))^2 &= \left(\sum_{i=1}^{k}|x^i-y^i|\right)^2\\&= \sum_{i=1}^k|x^i-y^i|^2+2\sum_{1\le i<j\le k}|x^i-y^i||x^j-y^j|\\ &\ge\sum_{i=1}^k|x^i-y^i|^2\\&=(d_2(x,y))^2.\end{align}$$